# How do I load all my JS files via index.js file for my RequireJS/AngularJS POC?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, requirejs, jspm

I am new to Node.js, NPM, JSPM, and Require.js and need help loading my Node package via the index.js file for a working RequireJS/AngularJS Proof of Concept (POC).   The RequireJS/AngularJS POC uses both JSPM and NPM packages.  However I am only able to load one JavaScript file from the Node package at a time instead of load the whole directory via the index.js file.

How do I load all my JS files via index.js file for my RequireJS/AngularJS POC?

Please clone RequireJS/AngularJS POC from here: https://github.com/byte-pushers/bytepushers-common-js/tree/features/BPCJ-23

I get the following error message when line 7 is uncommented out and line 9 is commented out in the byte-pushers/bytepushers-common-js/src/main/webapp/main.js file:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "com.bytepushers.base.app.js" has not been
>   loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

I get a successfully deployed app when line 7 is commented out and line 9 is uncommented out in the byte-pushers/bytepushers-common-js/src/main/webapp/main.js file.

Any help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: I am having the same problem, too!  Is there a difference in the use of require() method?  This there one require() method RequireJs and different require() method for NPM/JSPM packages?